# onConfigurationChanged() is not called for android:configChanges="density"

Tags: android, onconfigurationchanged

I added android:configChanges="density" for the activity in Manifest file. But I am not getting the onConfigurationChanged() callback

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".ClientActivity" android:configChanges="density">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I mentioned below the onConfigurationChanged() method. Actually I am not doing anything inside that one. If I get the call back I want to proceed further.

```
    @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your onConfigurationChanged method implementation?

Comment: Hello Tomerpacific, I added my onConfigurationChanged() method also. First of all I am not getting the callback. If I get the callback I will proceed further. Please check and help me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

add in manifest

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

add in activity.

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            Log.d("OrientationMyApp", "Current Orientation : Landscape");

        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Log.d("OrientationMyApp", "Current Orientation : Portrait");
        // Your magic here for portrait mode
      }
   }
```

Comment: Hello Pratik, Thanks for your reply. Actually I am changing the ScreenZoom. For that as I know android:configChanges="density" is the required property we need to add in Manifest. For only density I am not getting the callback. Can you please check and help me if you have any solution for this problem. Thank you

Comment: android:configChanges you can add density option.

Comment: Hello Pratik, I added density option already in the manifest. I mentioned the same code above. Even I am not getting the callback.

Comment: newConfig.densityDpi using through get dpi

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue and it was driving me crazy, what fixed for me was adding smallestScreenSize:

```
android:configChanges="density|smallestScreenSize"
```

I already had `screenSize|screenLayout|layoutDirection` as well for other reasons, those might be necessary too. I would suggest experimenting with all the possible attributes for `android:configChanges` until it works.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#config